# Use of "Pointers" or References for "memory management" in python?

Tags: python, pointers, memory, reference

How might one go about constructing something like a Linked List in python. I realize that python is not low level. But suppose I have a very large object, and I want to contain a reference to this large object in instances of another class:

```
class LargeObject:

    def __init__(self):
        # use lots of memory


class SmallObject:

    def __init__(self, large_object_ref):
        self.large_object_ref = large_object_ref

    # ...


largeObj = LargeObject()
smallObj = SmallObject(largeObj) # What happens in memory?
```

I want to ensure that `self.large_object_ref` never becomes a *deep copied* instance of `LargeObject` in memory, how do i prevent this/ensure this?

I admit I know very little about python's memory model or management, as one isn't  really supposed to have to in Python. I am familiar with C/++ though so I am borrowing terms and ideas from that area.

Answer (score 0):

Python is [pass-by-assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference) which is basically equal to pass-by-reference for mutable objects (and most of the user-created objects are mutable).